# Combo Box sometimes doesn't contain all rows that it should

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2016 database with:

-2 tables with a one-to-many relationship

-A form that has a subform.

On the main form, I have an unbound Combo Box (cboSeries) with 'qryShowAll' as the record source, and this combo box controls what records appear in the subform.

It all works fine most of the time, but the (bizarre) problem is every once in a while, when the database is opened, the combo box does not contain all the rows that it should (most of the time it does, but sometimes it doesn't). When this problem occurs, it seems to always be missing the same rows.

qryShowAll:

```
SELECT S.SeriesID, S.SeriesName, ((SELECT Count(*) FROM Episodes as E WHERE E.SeriesID = S.SeriesID AND E.Watched = true) & "/" & (SELECT Count(*) FROM Episodes as E1 WHERE E1.SeriesID = S.SeriesID))
FROM Series AS S
ORDER BY S.SeriesName;
```

Including some VBA that might be relevant...

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

cboSeries.RowSource = "qryShowAll"
cboSeries.Requery

Me.cboSeries.SetFocus
Me.cboSeries = Me.cboSeries.ItemData(0)

' Find the record that matches the control.
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
rs.FindFirst "[SeriesID] = " & str(Nz(Me![cboSeries], 0))
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub cboSeries_AfterUpdate()

' Find the record that matches the control.
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
rs.FindFirst "[SeriesID] = " & str(Nz(Me![cboSeries], 0))
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
     
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of cboSeries properties]

Like I said, it only happens sometimes, and I can't figure out what's triggering it. Any ideas of steps I can take to diagnose what is causing the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I -think- I have fixed it.

Tried changing the sql to use DCount() instead of SELECT Count(*) and it seems to have done the trick. No idea why, but I have closed/opened the database about 20 times and the bug has not happened.

Thanks all for reading. Admins - would you like to remove this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Set the RowSource of cboSeries permanently to qryShowAll and remove these two lines:

```vb
cboSeries.RowSource = "qryShowAll"
cboSeries.Requery
```

and it will load when the form opens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this and tested by opening / closing the database about 10 or 15 times, and the bug still happened 2 of those times. Your suggestion has not fixed it :(